# I was unable to refer bean to client interceptor

Tags: java, spring, soap

I was trying to convert xml based bean configuration to annotations based configuration for new application. I got stuck adding clientinterceptor bean referring in annotation based approach.

I have tried adding the below approach, unfortunately it is not working tomcat is failing exactly failing at my interceptor code :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:/envs/${env}/vendors-service.properties"})
public class WebServiceClientConfig {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @Value("${bcus.ws.security.client.interceptor}")
    private String securityInterceptor;
    @Bean(name = "deviceService")
    public DeviceServiceImpl deviceService(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        DeviceServiceImpl deviceService = new DeviceServiceImpl();
        List<ClientInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        interceptors.add((ClientInterceptor) applicationContext.getBean(securityInterceptor));
        deviceService.setInterceptors((ClientInterceptor[]) interceptors.toArray());
        return deviceService;
    }
```

```
    <bean id="deviceService" class="com.barclaycardus.svc.common.proxy.device.DeviceServiceImpl" parent="baseJaxbService">
          <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory" />
           <property name="defaultUri" value="${device.service.url}" />
            <property name="interceptors">
                <list>
                    <ref bean="${bcus.ws.security.client.interceptor}" />
                </list>
            </property>
     </bean>
```

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'deviceService' defined in class path resource [com/barclaycardus/svc/vendorgateway/core/config/WebServiceClientConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.barclaycardus.svc.vendorgateway.core.deviceservice.DeviceServiceImpl]: Factory method 'deviceService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named
```

Comment: The XML approach is working code

Answer (score 0):

you get probably the `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` from `applicationContext.getBean(securityInterceptor)`

That means either that the value of

```
    @Value("${bcus.ws.security.client.interceptor}")
    private String securityInterceptor;
```

is not resolved correctly or that you have not defined this bean or it is not yet loaded. But i'm not sure about the last point.

Please post your bean definition for the `ClientInterceptor` then it is easier to help.

Also please post the full exception it should look like:

`...NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '' available`

best regards,
WiPu

Comment: I have verified was able to print the value of securityInterceptor in local when I'm debugging the code it was failing exactly at (        interceptors.add((ClientInterceptor) applicationContext.getBean(securityInterceptor));
), target invocation exception then complete bean creation is failing.

I would say we need to figure it out the best approach to set the bean to client interceptor

Comment: I don't know your business case for using `${bcus.ws.security.client.interceptor}` instead wiring the ClientInterceptor directly or adding it as parameter into the method. You could work with `@Qualified` or `@Profile` to determine the right client interceptor. How looks your bean definition of the ClientInterceptor? Could you figur out which exception is the cause of the InvoctionTargetException?

Comment: Hey you're right the bean is not getting ${bcus.ws.security.client.interceptor}  instantatied  from the applicationcontext.xml. so its a value that value is a bean name from my compiled class. any idea how to get that as bean refer to client interceptor

Comment: So your interceptor bean is located in an XML file? Then make sure that this file is loaded with @ImportResource("classpath:yourFileWithPath.xml"). You can also check: https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-mixing-xml-and-javaconfig/ for further explanation. If you don't have an XML file you need to define your interceptor with a @Bean somewhere.

Comment: well I have fixed my bean issue, now I'm seeing the below error

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.springframework.ws.client.support.interceptor.ClientInterceptor

Comment: You can use `list.toArray(new ClientInterceptor[list.size()]);` or in case of Java8 `list.stream().toArray(ClientInterceptor[]::new);`